# properties of lim sup and lim inf

Tags: limits

$$\liminf_{n\to\infty}(x_n)=l,\quad\liminf_{n\to\infty}(y_n)=m,\quad\limsup_{n\to\infty}(x_n)=L,\quad\limsup_{n\to\infty}(y_n)=M.$$

I should mark correct statements. I tried to use properties of supremum and infimum, but probably don't know everything about it. So this my version.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Wnjc.jpg

Comment: Do you have some reasoning for your two answers? This is not generaly what stackexchange is meant for. That said, people here are usually willing to help, but you should prove that you have, indeed, put some effort to it, and try to pinpoint where are you stuck at. The community shouldn't just solve your homeworks for you.

Comment: I wrote that I tried to connect this exercise with supremum and infimum. It's cool if you know everything in every topic in mathematics, but I am not. And there is not much information about lim sup and lim inf. In conclusion I  provided something. All of us can make mistakes. If you can't help me or you don't want do it just watch other questions.

Comment: The very reason I actually replied is that I wanted to help, but it's a bit dificult to help you effectively, when you don't provide any information about what your problem actually is. Your description of what you have tried is as vague as it gets. You talk about "not knowing properties of sup/inf", but for this kind of exercise you shouldn't really need more then just the definitions of the terms.